# Editing XML to fit Schema/Template (or passing node values to other nodes in a template xml file?)

Tags: xml, xslt, xml-parsing

here is my challenge:

I have an xml export from an ecommerce site that outputs the details from an order. I don't have any control over the structure or node names for this xml file.

I have a piece of software I'm inputting that xml file to create work orders within our existing workflow to fulfill the orders. It expects xml using a certain format and node names, that I cannot change.

I need to edit the xml coming from the ecommerce site to fit the schema/template of the software it's going into so that the data maps to the correct fields on the work order. Can you suggest what the ideal piece would be to accomplish this?

Additional: If the solution could also handle logic to say if customer=ABC, then Purchase Order Number = 12345 that would kill two birds as once I get the XML fully functioning, my next challenge will be inserting logic to drive some variables.

happy to answer additional questions to full explain the challenge. As you can probably already tell, I'm learning as I go. Currently there is user input required for nearly every order that comes in that should be automated. Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

I have tried asking both parties involved to change their xml but they are unwilling.
I've been learning XML terminology and what other tools exist to accomplish this but struggling.

Comment: IMHO the best way to transform XML from one schema to another is to apply an XSL transformation. I suppose you know (or at least suspect) that, since you tagged your question as such. Beyond that, it's not clear what your question is; if you're looking for recommendations of specific XSLT tools then your question is off-topic here (not to mention that you gave us no information upon which to base such recommendation).

Comment: What is this "software it's going into"? Perhaps it has a built-in XSLT processor you can apply on the input (as some DBs do)?

Comment: A standard use case for XSLT. That's exactly what XSLT is designed for.